# Laplace's equation in Polar coordinate, an example?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

Consider Laplace's equation in polar coordinates $$ \frac {1}{r} \frac {\partial} {\partial r}  (r \frac {\partial U} {\partial r}) +  \frac {1} {r^2}  \frac {\partial^2 U} {\partial \theta^2} = 0$$ with $U(r,\theta)$ as the solution, subject to the boundary conditions:

> $$U(a,\theta)=\begin{cases}
> 2\theta && 0 < \theta <\pi\\
> 0 &&\pi< \theta < 2\pi\\
> \end{cases}$$

How can we calculate $\,U(0, \theta)$ ?

Comment: Did you get bored of asking about computability?

Comment: The above is not an _equation_ but an expression.

Comment: In polar coordinates on a disk, I think you can use separation of variables, although it is somewhat tedious. I can also give a probabilistic solution.

Comment: I have the last answer @Ian

Comment: Your boundary condition is discontinuous at $(a,pi) $.  I doubt there is a strong solution here.

Comment: I'm not sure @Paul

Comment: @Ian : When using separation of variable method, should it be solved for all three cases (separation variables being positive, zero or negative)?

Comment: From the answers below, we may conclude that $a = 2$ :-( But I would like to know the truth, actually ..

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach to evaluating the value at $r=0$ (and due to the way that Laplace's equation works, the value is independent of $\theta$) is to start by simplifying down the equation system. First, we integrate along $\theta$. This gives
$$
\frac1r\frac{d}{dr}\left(r \frac{d}{dr}\int Ud\theta\right)+\frac1{r^2}\left[\frac{\partial U}{\partial\theta}\right]_b^{b+2\pi} =0 
$$
Again, through the properties of Laplace's equation, we have that $\frac{\partial U}{\partial\theta}|_{\theta=b}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial\theta}|_{\theta=b+2\pi}$ except at the surface, where this relationship may not hold depending on the boundary conditions and the choice of $b$. If we choose $b=0$ or $b=\pi$, then the gradient is different on the two sides, and this could cause a problem (it actually doesn't, but it's better to be rigorous). Choosing any other value within the domain for $b$, we can see that the second term above is zero, and thus
$$
\frac1r\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{d}{dr}\int U d\theta\right) = 0
$$
This can be solved easily to obtain
$$
\int U d\theta = A + \frac{B}r
$$
for some integration constants $A$ and $B$. By the properties of Laplace's equation again, we know that the solution will not go infinite, and thus $B=0$. This gives us that $\int Ud\theta$ must remain constant for all $r$.

In particular, we have
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} U(a,\theta)d\theta = \pi^2
$$
and thus
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} U(0,\theta)d\theta = \pi^2
$$
but $U(0,\theta)=U(0,0)$ is a constant, and thus we have
$$
U(0,\theta) = \frac\pi2
$$

Comment: As a physicist, it completely escapes me how an angle $\theta$ can be integrated from a value of the radius $r$, namely $r=a$ , to a value $a+2\pi$.

Comment: @HandeBruijn - Ah, that's a side-effect of me writing up the main content before looking at the variable used to define the radius of the domain. I'll fix that up.

Comment: should there not be some dependence on the size of the radius in the answer?

Comment: @ellya - as it turns out, no. To see why, try rescaling the system - let $r=as$, so $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}=\frac1a\frac{\partial}{\partial s}$.

Comment: this then changes the equation, since the $\theta$ partial derivatives do not change with it, the Laplace equation is only rotation invariant. Have  a look at my answer below, I believe it is correct, and the radius comes into play

Answer (score 0):

If we use separation of variables, we can write: $u(r,\theta) = P(r) Q(\theta)$. The boundary conditions for $u$ yield $P(a) = U(a,\theta)$ and, because of periodicity, $Q(0) = Q(2\pi)$ and $Q'(0) = Q'(2\pi)$. Plugging the new definition for $u$ into the PDE results in:

$$r^2 \left( \frac{1}{r P} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r } \, r \frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}r}  \right) = -\frac{Q''}{Q} = \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, $$ where the primes denote differentiation with respect the independent variable. The problem for $Q(\theta)$ has as solution:

\begin{align}
\lambda = 0: \quad & Q = A \theta + B, \\
\lambda > 0: \quad & Q = A \cos{k \theta} + B \sin{k \theta}, \\
\lambda < 0: \quad & Q = A \cosh{\sqrt{|\lambda|} \theta} + B \sinh{\sqrt{|\lambda|} \theta},
\end{align} $k^2 = \lambda$, where the periodicity condition remains to be satisfied. For $\lambda = 0$ we find $A = 0$, while for $\lambda < 0$, $A = B = 0$. For the case $\lambda > 0$, the only nontrivial solution is that corresponding to $k = n = 1,2, \ldots$ (i.e., $k$ is an integer) and therefore:

$$ Q_n(\theta) = A_n \cos{n \theta} + B_n \sin{n \theta}$$

The problem for $P(r)$ reduces to solving an Euler equation, which upon trying solutions of the type $P(r) = r^s$ yields $s^2-n^2= 0$ and therefore $s = \pm n$. The bounded solution (that for which $|P(0)|<\infty$) is therefore given by:

$$ P_n(r) = C_n r^n $$

When you impose the boundary condition at $r=a$ you can find the constant of integration $C_n$.

I hope you find this useful.

If somebody finds any typo or any other type of fail in my discussing of the problem, please let me know. Cheers!

---

Note that we can let $n = 0$ as a solution for the case $\lambda = 0$ since $Q_0(\theta) = A_0$ (which plays the role of the constant $B$)

Comment: I misunderstand, what is the last answer for $U(0, \theta)$ ?

Comment: It seems that the OP only asks for $U(0,\theta)$ ; I wonder if that can be achieved via complex function analysis.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler approach for a question like this, since the function $U$ is harmonic it satisfies the mean value property (my assumption by the way is that $0\le r\le a$), and so $$U(0,\theta)=U(0,0)=\frac{1}{|B_a|}\int_{B_a(0)}U(r,\theta)\,dr\,d\theta=\frac{1}{|B_1(0)|a}\int_{\partial B_a(0)}U(a,\theta)\,d\theta$$
$$=\frac{1}{a\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}U(a,\theta)\,d\theta=\frac{1}{a\pi}\int_0^{\pi}2\theta\,d\theta=\frac{\pi^2}{a\pi}=\frac{\pi}{a}.$$
Note that $U(0,\theta)=U(0,0)$, because rotating a radius of zero does nothing.

Comment: As a physicist, it completely escapes me how $U(a,\theta)$ shall be dimensionless (an angle) while $U(0,\theta)=\pi/a$ would have the dimension of $\mbox{length}^{-1}$.

Comment: @HandeBruijn http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I believe you have made a mistake in applying the mean value property. In the step in which you apply it, your units change. Notice that, in the wikipedia page you linked to, the $B$ integral has $r^n$ on the denominator, but the $\partial B$ integral has $r^{n-1}$ on the denominator. Which means that, essentially, your $\partial B_a(0)$ integral should now be multiplied by $r=a$, and that cancels the $a$ on the denominator... but also, there should now be an $n=2$ on the denominator. Giving $\pi/2$ as the answer, as I found in my answer.